# php multidimensional array get first date value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need help once again. I have an array and I need to extract earliest day weight value.

EDIT - EDIT - EDIT

```
array (
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '20110211',
    'Date' => '2011-02-11',
    'Weight' => '195',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => '20110213',
    'Date' => '2011-02-13',
    'Weight' => '160',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'id' => '20110310',
    'Date' => '2011-03-10',
    'Weight' => '200',
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'id' => '20110301',
    'Date' => '2011-03-01',
    'Weight' => '55',
  ),
  21 => 
  array (
    'id' => '20110215',
    'Date' => '2011-02-15',
    'Weight' => '120',
  ),
  25 => 
  array (
    'id' => '20110322',
    'Date' => '2011-03-22',
    'Weight' => '250',
  ),
)
```

I've edited this and this code works:

```
function sortByDate ($arr1, $arr2)
{
   return strcmp($arr1['Date'], $arr2['Date']);
}
// $arr is your array
usort($weight_tracker, 'sortByDate');
$earliest = $weight_tracker[0]['Weight'];
echo $earliest;
```

But since I have a form on this page which updates the array when array is updated - I got message Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in

EDIT -> I've re-declared this as string, hence the ERROR ! be careful when using global and includes as everything can become a mess ! PHP is forgiving, but that "forgiveness" can cost a lot of time later on...  :)

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: It would be easier for others to copy your code and work out a solution if you pasted properly formed arrays in PHP rather than the result of var_dump(), it means we have to type them out ourselves, just saying...

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but is `$weight_tracker` being accidentally reassigned to a string instead of array at some point? If this code is where the error occurs, it sounds like it's because `$weight_tracker` is a string when it should be an array.

Comment: On an unrelated note, it looks like the numeric keys in the big array are record IDs from a DB or something. Do those need to be preserved? Currently `usort()` renumbers them 0,1,2,etc. If you need to keep the original ID numbers, I'll update my answer for that.

Comment: @Cups - I know, but I'm not sure if I can paste 600 lines of code...  @Wiseguy - I'm looking at the code to see, but I think it's not reassigned to a string.... For this stuff I just need an Weight value recorded on earliest date (order and ID's are not important as the ID is actually a time-stamp for now but later on will be used for something different)

Comment: ABSOLUTELY CORRECT - I had an include where I re-declared it as a STRING :(  MY BAD !!!  THIS IS 100% WORKING SOLUTION !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort the array with a custom callback using [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) and then take the first element.

```
// $arr is your array
usort($arr, 'sortByDate');
$earliest = $arr[0];

function sortByDate ($arr1, $arr2)
{
   return strcmp($arr1['Date'], $arr2['Date']);
}
```

Comment: This works, but when page is updated I get Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in...  I've updated it in question

Comment: @Peter I don't see how this code would cause that error. Is it from something you added right after it? Maybe [this](http://informationideas.com/news/2006/06/14/fatal-error-cannot-use-string-offset-as-an-array-in/) will help.

Comment: Great... my bad - in one included file I've re-declared it as string - THANKS FOR HELP !

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it:

```
function filter_min($a, $b) {
  return ($a['Date'] < $b['date']) ? $a : $b;
}

$result = array_reduce($array, 'filter_min');
echo $result['Weight'];
```

Another way is to simply iterate over the array and find the smallest date.

Answer (score 0):

```
$smallest = null; // array index of entry with smallest weight.
foreach ($array as $idx => $data) {
    if (($data['Weight'] < $array[$smallest]['Weight']) || (is_null($smallest))) {
      $smallest = $idx; // found a small weight, so save the index
    }
}

echo $array[$smallest]['Date'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the dates are in reverse order with the latest date being pulled in first, and the earliest date last.  Will it always be like that?  If so, you can do this:

```
$index = count($array) - 1;
$earliestdate = $array[$index]['Date'];
```

You could also use `array_reverse()` to invert the array and make the first element the formerly last element.

If this is being pulled in from MySQL you could also alter the query to `ORDER BY 'Date' DESC` (or is it `ASC` that would get you what you want, can't remember)

Comment: Actually, they're not in order, but I agree with ordering in the DB query if possible/applicable.

Comment: Ah, you're right, didn't notice that 02-05-2011 was before 02-10-2011